# How to create a Batch file to copy zips in subfolders to another folder

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a folder called `Private`, which contains a number of subfolders. Each of those folders contain a number of zip files.

Now I would like to create a batch file to copy all the zips in all the subfolders containing the letters `Win` to another folder. The source path is `F:\_QA\Private\` and the destination is `F:\_QA\Zips\`.

I initially tried just for testing to copy all the zips using

```
XCOPY F:\_QA\Private\ F:\_QA\Zips\
```

which didn't seem to work.

Comment: Apologies for the vague post.

The ZIP files in folders containing win should all be copied to F:\_QA\Zips without replicating the directory structure.

I have tried various code snippets in various posts here on stackoverflow, without success. As for my original code, it is one I tried after reading the XCOPY page at https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html.

Comment: Possibly: ```@PushD F:\_QA\Private 2>NUL && (If Exist ..\Zips\. (For /D %%G In (*win*) Do @If Exist "%%G\*.zip" Copy /Y "%%G\*.zip" ..\Zips) & PopD)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `dir` command which can output all zip files recursively, and then filter the output and copy the results. Here is a tested script that does just that:

```
@echo off

set "fromPath=F:\_QA\Private"
set "destinationPath=F:\_QA\Zips"

if not exist "%destinationPath%" mkdir "%destinationPath%"

:: The findstr is to filter a case-sensitive "Win", as the dir command
:: is always case-insensitive. Feel free to remove that part.
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir "%fromPath%\*Win*.zip" /b /s ^| findstr /r /c:"\\[^^\\]*Win[^^\\]*.zip$"') do (
    echo Copying "%%A"...
    copy /y "%%A" "%destinationPath%" > NUL
)

echo.
echo Complete!
pause
```

First we find all zip files recursively in that folder, then we filter the output with a the following [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) expression:

`\\[^^\\]*Win[^^\\]*.zip$`

This filters only zip files with Win in the name.

See [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) and [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) for more details regarding those commands.

Comment: `if not exist "%destinationPath%"` will fail to achieve the desired effect if an extensionless file named `zips`, _(case insensitve)_, exists in `F:\_QA`. Also there is absolutely no need/benefit in using back-quotes in the `for /f` loop, or in using the `/c` option with the `findstr.exe` utility. Your `dir` command can pick up directories containing the substring `win`, and which additionally end with the shortname substring `.zip`; or files in `Private`, (not stated)! The question stipulates that the directories include the substring `Win` not that each of the zip files have that substring!

Comment: @Compo You're right, I misunderstood that he meant a subfolder containing `Win`. I modified my answer to address that. Thanks for pointing that out.
I addressed some of your other, in my opinion,  more nitpicky comments too.

Comment: You don't have to fix them, if you don't want to. Some people do not want  accept advice which can improve their existing, or future, code, or simply improve its efficiency. That's fine, but as you have not improved your `if not exist`, or `dir` commands, and have seemingly decided that `/c` is still required with `findstr`, I will leave this comment in place for future readers to let them know there is further improvement which can be made. I'm also not entirely confident that the OP is working with a multi-level subdirectory structure, rather than a single level of `Private`'s children.

Comment: BTW, as ```\``` characters cannot exist within a directory or filename, it seems like using `[^^\\]` could be simplified. Also, the OP may not wish to include, for example, `.zipx` files, (which could be prevented with the addition of a single character). Please also note that `.` has a special meaning with `/r` in `findstr`, which means that yours is representing any character, not an explicit period.

Comment: @Compo I'm ensuring that it matches with the **parent** directory of the zip file, otherwise it could match a parent directory if that ever changed to contain Win somewhere. Thanks, modified the expression.

Comment: BTW, what about `.ZIP` or `.Zip` files?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding, I haven't had time to return to this.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding, I haven't had time to return to this.

Thank you both for your comments and suggestions. Unfortunately the example by Styris doesn't seem to do anything. This is the source path:

F:\_QA\_DS\_Bxxx\_Rxxxx\Rxxxx Pxxxxxxx\Pxxxxxx\

Inside that are 13 folders with numerals as folder names, e.g. 6865, 21955, etc. Each of those folders contain *.zip files. The zip file names are a mixture of letters and numbers, containing Win.

So all the zips matching ****Win***.zip should be copied to a single folder, which is at

F:\_QA\_DS\_Bxxx\_Rxxxx\Pxxxxxx\

Comment: @TheGit Thanks for clarifying, that's what we weren't sure about. I edited my answer, which should now work as desired.

Comment: Thank you! The altered answer does the job.